# How to leave padding below an image when text wraps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.blogimgarea
{
width: 38%;
padding-right: 26px;
float:left;
}
img{max-width:100%}
.blogtextarea
{
 width:55%;
 padding:22px 32px 0 0;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="newpostregion pt70">
 <div class="blogimgarea">
  <img class="featblogimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Keeptidy_ask.png" title="In The News">
 </div>
 <div class="blogtextarea">
  <div class="titlelineblog">In The News</div>
  <div class="metalineblog">
   By sitemanager  |  Friday, Feb 12, 2016  |  0 Comments
  </div>
  <div class="contentblog">
  <div class="domore">
   <h2>Our Plastic Surgeon In the News</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et viverra nisl. Nullam lorem tellus, eleifend eu dolor ut, consectetur venenatis velit. Mauris vestibulum sapien ac neque rutrum aliquam. Curabitur diam eros, luctus ac mattis eu, lacinia in turpis. Etiam sed commodo risus. Phasellus odio augue, mollis vel risus nec, vulputate maximus tellus. Duis accumsan, neque at egestas vestibulum, nisi sem ornare tortor, nec consequat lacus sem vitae lectus. Cras ac nibh et velit porttitor placerat eget nec mauris. Vivamus ut lacus non lorem volutpat euismod sit amet ac neque. Pellentesque imperdiet semper ligula, ac pharetra est pretium at. Quisque et venenatis ligula, in eleifend mi.

   Vivamus placerat metus a neque placerat, tincidunt tincidunt magna lacinia. Morbi eget orci arcu. Suspendisse tristique nibh velit, non volutpat dui aliquet at. Cras lacinia nibh sed leo viverra condimentum. In et quam mattis, eleifend ipsum nec, facilisis felis. Vivamus suscipit arcu ut magna laoreet convallis. Morbi suscipit semper magna in dignissim. Vivamus cursus erat sed nulla dictum malesuada at eget ex. Curabitur cursus tincidunt nisl. Praesent in viverra nibh. Donec congue est nulla, nec interdum purus ullamcorper quis. 
  </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to resolve a html structure which looks like this:

http://puu.sh/n5lSB/13745d19f0.png

I am well versed with html and jquery but yet I unable to figure out how to leave this empty space on bottom-left of image like this:

http://puu.sh/n5lQ3/f4547056d2.png

I can easily do less/more JavaScript based code yet cannot think of way leaving the empty space below image. Any pointed/suggestion will be really helpful as I have spend considerable time but all in vain as it looks easier but its bit challenging.

Comment: Where's your markup? Where's your CSS?

Comment: do you really want that partial wrap on the text? So that it sort of goes halfway under the image? Or do you want what would, in the end, amount to two columns?

Comment: I need that partial gap @dgig in the red http://puu.sh/n5mur/e4a13d8f7d.png this is actually a design I am working on

Comment: Your question is about to be closed. Add some code to salvage it. It would also be helpful to tell us what that space will be used for (in general terms).

Comment: The solution is a lot more simple when you think of it as a hanging indent (which usually uses a negative margin) and padding for the column. Edit: or floats.  I feel dumb now.

Comment: Adding code, Please hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is `float:left`, and it's *before* the paragraph, you can add padding or margin to the paragraph and the image will simply push the text in further.

```
img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
img+p {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4u3rrhk9/)

If the image is floating and *inside* the paragraph, you'll need to assign it a negative margin instead:

```
.indent {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.indent img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hj5kaym6/)

Comment: Thank you for providing good explanation as well as not just one 2 solutions.